# 2D XNA - Draw a Circle

Tags: c#, xna

Yo, Hi everybody

Is there any Way to draw a circle? I don't want to use a Texture/sprite to draw a circle Because the Player is the Circle so the Circle Should move ... and also I'm Trying to make it so the Player/Circle's Size gets bigger and bigger When he eats some food blablabla...

anyways, if anybody knows how to do it please Tell me.

OTHERWISE : IS THERE A WAY TO CHANGE A TEXTURE HEIGHT / WIDTH , THEN I WILL MAKE A SIMPLE CIRCLE TEXTURE AND CHANGE HEIGHT / WIDTH OF IT.

Thanks.

Comment: Any progress so far? if not, let me know and i will try to give a code exaple. if so, pls mark someone's or my answer as accepted when they were of use

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3D primitives like 'Someone' :> already posted or use the C3.XNA.Primitives2D libary where you can use a extension for SpriteBatch to draw a circle

```
public static void DrawCircle(this SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 center, float radius, int sides, Color color, float thickness);
```

If you use the same value for radius and thickness the circle appears filled.
I didn't find the offizial download link, but there are also uploads at sourceforge.

Also you can generate a circle dynamically via code like:

```
public static Texture2D GenerateCircleTexture(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, int radius, Color color, float sharpness)
    {
        int diameter = radius * 2;
        Texture2D circleTexture = new Texture2D(graphicsDevice, diameter, diameter, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        Color[] colorData = new Color[circleTexture.Width * circleTexture.Height];
        Vector2 center = new Vector2(radius);
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < circleTexture.Width; colIndex++)
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < circleTexture.Height; rowIndex++)
            {
                Vector2 position = new Vector2(colIndex, rowIndex);
                float distance = Vector2.Distance(center, position);

                // hermite iterpolation
                float x = distance / diameter;
                float edge0 = (radius * sharpness) / (float)diameter;
                float edge1 = radius / (float)diameter;
                float temp = MathHelper.Clamp((x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0), 0.0f, 1.0f);
                float result = temp * temp * (3.0f - 2.0f * temp);

                colorData[rowIndex * circleTexture.Width + colIndex] = color * (1f - result);
            }
        }
        circleTexture.SetData<Color>(colorData);

        return circleTexture;
    }
```

Sharpness below 1f blurs the circle.

Comment: I do not have enough reps to comment @Someone 's answer but he is right on his comment. Using vertices will be the fastes and most flexible, I just wanted to give some alternatives

Comment: but how can i change the size each time then?

Comment: Well with the C3.XNA.Primatives2D libary you just pass the radius (which determins the size) to the .DrawCircle method. When you dynamicly generate the texture via code you can either pass a scaling to the draw method of the SpriteBatch or generate a new texture when the size changed (also by passing a different radius)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to draw primitives (e.g. circles) is in 3D:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx

Or you can load a texture that is 1*1, stretch it into a line and then use a bunch of those lines to make a circle.
Use:

```
public void Draw (
         Texture2D texture,
         Vector2 position,
         Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
         Color color,
         float rotation,
         Vector2 origin,
         Vector2 scale,
         SpriteEffects effects,
         float layerDepth
)
```

to stretch the texture.

Or you can just use a circle texture and stretch it.

If you are making something like agar.io then you might want to use a texture combined with the circle primitive so you can make the circle 'wobbly'.

Comment: Yeh , im making something like agar.io ... i'm goin to try out this and let you know ^^ thanks.

Comment: I recommend making the circle out of the 1*1 textures and stretching them which will work in 2D however I'm not entirely sure about the 3D primitives - if you use the 3D primitives the chances are you are going to have to start messing with viewports and lighting etc.

Comment: Bashn's answer should work as well but then you are going to have to start downloading and setting up more stuff which you probably won't want. (However generating a new texture for every circle could get very slow if you want the circle to wobble)

Comment: i don't need the wobble effects for now ... i just want to draw the circle and make it go big everytime. so , going to try your answer and Bashn's answer.